# Django X-CSRFToken have been set but still get 403 forbidden

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I've developed an Django file upload API which receive the posted data from client and save the data as file.

According to the [Django CSRF manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/), the HTTP request header should set X-CSRFToken with the csrftoken cookie value. I've set the X-CSRFToken  by the code below, but the POST request still forbidden(403) by Django server as the picture below shows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var authid
    $.get("http://localhost:8000/v1/getAuthID?username=testuser1&password=123", function(data){
        authid = data["authid"];
        var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
        console.log(csrftoken);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        });

        url = "http://localhost:8000/v1/file".replace("{authid}", authid).replace("{token}", csrftoken)
        $.post(url, function(data){
        })
    })
})
```

[image]

How did you overcome the Django CSRF by send POST request to Django server?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you so sure it's an CSRF issue? I don't see anything wrong with your CSRF handling at first glance.

Comment: I got the "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." when I checked the 403 response. And I can get the same response when the X-CSRFToken adding code removed.

Comment: Ok, can you check if the cookie sent in the POST request matches the header?

Comment: Thanks @knbk for the checking! I can never get a cookie named "csrftoken " if I cleared the previous cookie at browser.

Comment: It seems Django did not send cookie csrftoken to client

Comment: I guess you're not using `{% csrf_token %}` in any template? In that case, try to decorate your views with [`@ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie). It should be on the view that handles the GET request _before_ the POST request.

Comment: Yes, I just develop API by Django. And my front-end is written by HTML&JS, no Django template used.

Comment: I've set the ensure_csrf_cookie, and Django server sent the cookie by HTTP header at "Set-Cookie". But the cookie from header cannot set browser cookie, so $.cookie('csrftoken') didn't work. Finally, I use @csrf_exempt to tell the view not check csrf token. Since my API should be accessed by another domain with POST/GET request. There is security concern by this way, so I will enhance my API security by other methods. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Move the ajaxSetup outside of your AJAX success function as it is required for the request, not after it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var authid;
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    console.log(csrftoken);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    });


    $.get("http://localhost:8000/v1/getAuthID?username=testuser1&password=123", function(data){
        authid = data["authid"];

        url = "http://localhost:8000/v1/file".replace("{authid}", authid).replace("{token}", csrftoken)
        $.post(url, function(data){
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:) But still got 403 error with your code.

Comment: Is it a typo that your console screen shot is requesting localhost:8003 but your code snippet is localhost:8000 or is that the intension?

Comment: The JS is run at the local website of localhost:8003. And Django server run at localhost:8000.

Comment: I think the problem would be that unless you're using a csrf token / cookie generated by the Django server on :8000, you won't get around this issue as you are performing cross site requests. It'll work locally, but in production, unless you're using the same domain / sub-domains then you'll have issues

Comment: Thanks @justcompile, the CORS have been enabled by Access-Control-Allow-Origin set for * .  So I think this is not cross domain issue.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I'm pretty sure CORS are a browser thing, so wouldn't have any affect on CSRF

Answer (score 1):

I use the javascript code below that takes care of the whole CSRF topic for ajax calls:

```
// This function gets cookie with a given name
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

/*
The functions below will create a header with csrftoken
*/

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Just include it after JQuery.

Comment: Thanks @Danial for the code : ). getCookie('csrftoken') is not work for my situation. I didn't use Django template, and I communicate with the API developed by Django only by JS. So I cannot get the cookie 'csrftoken'. It seems this is because the response cookie got by Ajax cannot set browser cookie. I'm still researching it... ...